# Disable supersu permission dialog

Tags: android, su

Is it possible to disable the "grant/deny" popup dialog when my app needs to perform tasks that require root access? I have full control of the device the app will run on (internal project), the device is rooted and it has supersu 2.x app.

[This](http://su.chainfire.eu/#updates-permission) tells me that I need to declare the `android.permission.ACCESS_SUPERUSER` permission for my app to disable the popup, but it has no effect.

Is there a simple way to solve this (without changing the option i supersu app settings)?

Answer (score 5):

Remove the SuperSU APK (usually either `/system/app/Superuser.apk` or `/data/app/eu.chainfire.supersu*.apk` or `/system/app/SuperSU/SuperSU.apk`) and `rm -rf` the `/data/data/eu.chainfire.supersu` directory, and the `su` command will always grant access without showing the prompt.

If you're making a custom firmware image for your project, just exclude the APK.

Note that `pm path eu.chainfire.supersu` from an adb shell will give you the exact path for the APK.

Comment: It depends on the app you want to develop, but if you are working on something useful (not trying to harm / rob etc. your users), then this is probably the worst advice you can give!

Comment: "I have full control of the device the app will run on (internal project)"

Answer (score 3):

You can't decide in you app to disable the prompt. That's a security measure which no app can change.

If your device is rooted and you have supersu, you can still get rid of the dialog. You have to change a setting in supersu: **Settings --> Access --> Default access --> Grant**

Comment: What is the point of `android.permission.ACCESS_SUPERUSER` then?

Comment: @Misterer It just gives you permission to ask for SU access, it doesn't actually grant it.  Think about it, if any app could get SU access without the user specifically OKing that, there would be a security nightmare.

Comment: The user is presented with requested permission list when installing the app. If they decide they want the app that declares su requirement, it means they accept that and allow it. I don't see the problem here.

Comment: @Simon is completely right. Think about *any* app been able to do *anything* without the user's consent. That should not happen, and Chainfire (creator of SuperSu) won't enable what you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible, you can't interfere with the logic of another app, i.e. the one showing the popup when **su** is accessed (for example *Superuser*).